# getting "Unkown id: insmod" error during init module

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, odroid

i have built kernel for odroid-xu by the help of instruction given
[HERE](http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:odroid-xu)

kernel source:- https://github.com/hardkernel/linux/tre ... android-jb
i have used below commands to build the zImage:-

- Configure Kernel: make odroidxu_android_defconfig
- Build Kernel and Modules: make -j8

to build kernel image, modules.

when i tried to load my module i gets below errors

```
255|shell@android:/sdcard/Drivers/20141014 $ su insmod usbnet.ko
Unknown id: insmod
```

Help me to find out the solution of this. Am i doing something wrong in zImage building.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong command for loading module ,su used for superuser you are giving insmod as user to su that's why you got this error.

Also for loading driver in kernel you need to be root user so first root your device and try following command

```
root@android:/sdcard/Drivers/20141014 $ insmod usbnet.ko
```